# PHP return type hinting, object OR a boolean?

Tags: php, php-7, type-hinting

So I know that I can do return type hinting in php7. I can do an object return hint with:

```
function getUser($pdo, $username) : User
{

}
```

where User is the object being returned.

However, if the user isn't found in the SQL, returning `'false'` instead of a User object gives:

> Uncaught TypeError: Return value of UserFind::findUser() must be an instance of User, boolean returned

But what if the SQL can't find the user? How can I return a boolean, false, if the user doesn't exist? Should I just ignore return type hinting in this scenario?

EDIT:  I looked at the other question, 'Nullable return types in php 7' and while my question is almost identical, I want to extend my question by asking if there would ever be a way to return one of two types. For example return an object or a string if the object is nonexistant?

Comment: I always find questions like this strange, because my first reaction is always "use an exception". And then I remember that exceptions are, like many other things, the so-called "redheaded stepchild" in PHP.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams PHP just generally employs another approach to exceptions in general. Python for example uses them for nearly everything. PHP does not. Exceptions being fairly slow in general doesn't help the case either.

Comment: Having explicitly two different return types from a method always seems to smell a bit to me. What does your calling code need to do if the user isn't found (ie: you return `false`)? It's basically an exceptional circumstance, so I think an exception is a better way to deal with it. It's just a pity PHP doesn't have the idea of null objects: that'd be a better way to go than a mixed return type. Given that's not an option: an exception is the way to go I think.

Answer (score 21):

What you're talking about is called a Union Type. There's [considerable discussion about it in Internals](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types)

> This RFC proposes the ability to define multiple possible types for a parameter or return type and calls them “union types”. A value passes the type-check for a union type if the value would pass any one of the members the union. A vertical bar (OR) is placed between each of the two or more types.
>
> Here is an example of a parameter accepting either an array or a Traversable and no other types:
>
> ```
> function (Array | Traversable $in) {
>     foreach ($in as $value) {
>         echo $value, PHP_EOL;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> There can be more than two types in the union. As an example, it is somewhat common for a routine that interacts with a database to have one of three results:
>
> 1. Successfully found results
> 2. Successfully found no results
> 3. There was an error

This is all targeted at PHP 7.1 but isn't up for a vote yet (let alone looking like it will pass).

So what about your issue? I would say, at least for now, don't type hint your return. Just issue a doc block that says it can return `User` or `false`

```
/**
 * @param \PDO $pdo
 * @param string $username
 * @return User|false
 */
```

Comment: Or you could throw somethink like Exception_NotFound()

Comment: The propose has been voted and it was declined. So no union types.

Comment: [Version 2 of Union Types](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2) has been voted for and passed. It will be coming to PHP 8.0