# PHP dynamic return type hinting

Tags: php, types

Suppose I have the following PHP function:

```
/**
 * @param string $className
 * @param array $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
function getFirstObject($className, $parameters) {
    // This uses a Doctrine DQl builder, but it could easily replaced
    // by something else. The point is, that this function can return
    // instances of many different classes, that do not necessarily
    // have common signatures.
    $builder = createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('obj')
        ->from($className, 'obj');
    addParamClausesToBuilder($builder, $parameters, 'obj');
    $objects = $builder
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return empty($objects) ? null : array_pop($objects);
}
```

Basically, the function always returns either an instance of the class specified with the `$className` parameter or `null`, if something went wrong. The only catch is, that I do not know the full list of classes this function can return. (at compile time)

**Is it possible to get type hinting for the return type of this kind of function?**

In Java, I would simply use generics to imply the return type:

```
static <T> T getOneObject(Class<? extends T> clazz, ParameterStorage parameters) {
    ...
}
```

I am aware of the manual type hinting, like

```
/** @var Foo $foo */
$foo = getOneObject('Foo', $params);
```

but I would like to have a solution that does not require this boilerplate line.

To elaborate: I am trying to write a wrapper around Doctrine, so that I can easily get the model entities that I want, while encapsulating all the specific usage of the ORM system. I am using PhpStorm.

** edited function to reflect my intended usage. I originally wanted to keep it clean of any specific use case to not bloat the question. Also note, that the actual wrapper is more complex, since I also incorporate model-specific implicit object relations and joins ect.

Comment: There is a bug in your question: `that I do not know the full list of classes this function can return` vs `aware of the manual type hinting`  if you dont now in the first place, how will you tyephint it, only solution: all classes have to implement the same `interface` and this interface is then used for return typ `in PHP7 only` like  `functionA : interfacX (){}`

Comment: There is no multi-type hinting in php (yet): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873567/php-return-type-hinting-object-or-a-boolean

Comment: Side note: in php this `/** @var Foo $foo */` allowes php tools like PHPStrom to give u the right list of method/props of a the returned class, if a 1-1 typehint is given.

Comment: @MarcB I see voting decided against the feature. On the other hand I just scrolled through quickly. Is it off the table?

Comment: @Nordenheim: no idea. don't really pay much attention to php's development stuff. beats me why they wouldn't allow it, since pretty much all of php's core functions do dual-type returns already anyways. some resource/value, or a false for failure. even if they didn't do it as a general "return any type thing", allowing "specific-type-or-boolean" would at least allow userlevel code to replicate what core functions are already capable of.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions It's not a bug, it's a feature! :D The `getObjects(...)` function can return any instance of classes that are added and removed at runtime. When I use the function though, I know exactly what specific class I want, because I specified it in the function arguments. Basically, I have to say two things: (1) "Give me a dog." and (2) "This thing I just got is a dog."... Number 2 seems necessary in this use case, but it is a completely redundant statement.

Comment: But `PHP` is not `JAVA`. ;-)) So OOP is kinda different in PHP an way simpler as in Java :-) Hope you find a way and you will not end in a Buggy Feature :))

Comment: @MarcB that's not really what he asked for. the union types will not solve it. It's not about defining multiple return types - it's about defining the return type as the classname given in first argument. The main problem is that php does not have types - classes are passed as string. But at least phpdoc could support it..

Answer (score 2):

I use phpdoc `@method` for this purpose. For example, I create `AbstractRepository`  class which is extend by other Repository classes. Suppose we have `AbstractRepository::process(array $results)` method whose return type changes according to the class that extends it.
So in sub class:

```
/**
* @method Car[] process(array $results)
*/
class CarRepo extends AbstractRepository {
    //implementation of process() is in the parent class
}
```

**Update 1:**

You could also use `phpstan/phpstan` library. Which is used for static code analyses and you can use it to define [generic return types](https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-in-php-using-phpdocs):

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param class-string<T> $className
 * @param int $id
 * @return T|null
 */
function findEntity(string $className, int $id)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: To mark process() as a static function, write `/** @method static Car[] process(array $results) */`. Further details about the `@method`-annotation can be found at [phpdoc.org](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html#:~:text=The%20%40method%20tag%20allows%20the,case%20'void'%20is%20implied.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHPStorm or VSCode (with the extension PHP Intelephense by Ben Mewburn) there is an implementation named [metadata](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html) where you could specify your own type-hinting based on your code doing the magic inside. So the following should work (as it did on VSCode 1.71.2)

```php
<?php
namespace PHPSTORM_META {    
    override(\getFirstObject(0), map(['' => '$0']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can now be achieved with the IntellJ (IDEA/phpStorm/webStorm) plugin DynamicReturnTypePlugin:
https://github.com/pbyrne84/DynamicReturnTypePlugin